# Закрытие приложения

Tags: delphi

Как можно закрыть приложение, если я его пишу только с использованием WinApi, без окон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PostMessage(handle,WM_QUIT,0,0);
```

**UPD**

Можно еще проще:

```
application.terminate;
```

Comment: ОП хотел:

> без окон

И совершенно непонятно, что за мифический "*идентификатор приложения*".

Comment: @karmadro4, что же вы за нуб такой? Хватит цепляться ко всем людям! Троллите всех направо и налево...угомонитесь. По этому поводу я, наверное, обращусь в админимтрацию. Ведь пользы от вас никакой на форуме, а вот рейтинг, своими выходками, необоснованно забираете. И, кстати, вам повторно говорю, что надо бы вам подучить WinApi, раз вы даже не знаете, что такое "идентификатор приложения" .

Comment: То есть, *виликий гуру*, приносящий сотни пользы форуму, не может внятно объяснить *нубу* что такое *идентификатор приложения*? 
И в Спортлото написать не забудьте ;-)

> необоснованно забираете

Удивительно, откуда вообще у вас рейтинг, если на вопрос с пометой "пишу только с использованием WinApi", вы искрометно выдаёте: "application.terminate".

Comment: "application.terminate", это, как вариант, мистер тролль.

Comment: Начните лучше с обоснования "идентификатора приложения", а то миллионы *троллей* восторгаются полетом вашей фантазии на тему WinAPI ;-) А "вариант" совершенно не к месту, ибо в апишной программе не бывает объекта `Application`.

Comment: в апишной программе не бывает объекта Application.

Это понятно! "Как вариант" значит как вариант для Delphi приложения...не знаю даже, зачем вы вообще об это заговорили, ведь и дураку ваше утверждение понятно.

Comment: Ну раз и вам это утверждение понятно, то в чем ценность последней правки?

Comment: @karmadro4 - а в чем ценность ее обсуждения? И вообще - если вы можете ответить лучше, будьте так добры - ответьте.

Comment: @karmadro4, я обещал? [Получите!][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/106712/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @Asen, если забить в гугле имя функции PostMessage, то внезапно окажется, что первым ее параметром идет идентификатор окна, которое по условию задачи отсутствует:)

Comment: @insolor, на самом деле окно все равно может подразумеваться, хотя, не факт, что будет все работать.

> The message is posted to all top-level windows in the system, including 
> disabled or invisible unowned windows, overlapped windows, and pop-up 
> windows. The message is not posted to child windows

Comment: @Dex, а где взять хэндл окна, если окна как такового нет?

Comment: @insolor, ответ на этот вопрос, мы ждем от @Asen. Я лишь расширил ваш комментарий ибо `без окон != полное их отсутствие`.

Answer (score 5):

- Никто, кстати говоря, не упомянул `graceful` способа выйти из приложения *(по сравнению с [**ExitProcess**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx)),* который заключается в использовании функции [**PostQuitMessage.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945.aspx)

> Разница между `ExitProcess` и `PostQuitMessage` в том, что второй способ предполагает собой *более плавный* выход с точки зрения `Message Pump`.
>
> Сообщение `WM_QUIT` является **виртуальным,** что идеологически соответствует сообщению с низким приоритетом для `pull'a` из очереди.  С точки зрения практики это позволяет вашему приложению обработать все не-виртуальные *(то есть более приоритетные)* сообщения перед выходом из программы.
>
> Не сталкивался на практике, но, думаю, что потенциально вызов `ExitProcess` вполне себе может приводить к зрительным артефактам и какому-нибудь другому нежелательному `behavior'у`.

- Неплохую статью по теме можно почитать [**здесь.**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051104-33/?p=33453)

Answer (score 4):

Самое простое

```
ExitProcess(0)
```

Аргумент = 0, значит "без ошибки".

Answer (score 0):

можно вообще halt, но не советую злоупотреблять, так как трудно отлаживать.

Comment: halt - нерекомендовано...плохим стилем считается.

Comment: Насчет финализации вы неправы, цепочка вызовов отрабатывает прежде чем программа завершится.

Comment: > Насчет финализации вы неправы, цепочка вызовов отрабатывает прежде чем программа завершится.
Да, вы правы, исправлю ответ.
> halt - не рекомендовано...плохим стилем считается.
Плохим, согласен, я и не писал, что хорошим, даже пояснил почему способ сомнителен.

Comment: Лично я не вижу ничего плохого в `Halt`. Вероятно, можно предложить что-либо лучше, но это затруднительно сделать не видя код этого "WinAPI, без окон". Возможно, `Break` из цикла идеальный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Заведи булевую переменную isRunning и проверяй её в цикле обработки сообщений. Если она равна false, то прекращай цикл. Таким образом, программа завершится автоматически. Это будет правильнее, чем вызывать ExitProcess, потому что все объекты будут корректно удалены.